# Barnyard2 syslog output missing program name

Tags: snort

I am setting a security-onion instance that monitors the network and uses snort to inspect the traffic. I have configured barnyard2 to forward the logs to an external Syslog server using the line:

```
output alert_syslog_full: sensor_name so-ens192, server 10.0.0.132, protocol udp, port 514, operation_mode default
```

the Syslog server receives the alerts but it is unable to identify what is the application that generated the logs.

Instead of receiving something like:

```
Nov 12 09:33:50 barnyard2[62642]: [1:10482:6] ET INFO Session Traversal Utilities for NAT (STUN Binding Request obsolete rfc 3489 CHANGE-REQUEST attribute change IP flag false change port flag false) [Classification: Generic Protocol Command Decode] [Priority: 3]: <em0> {UDP} 10.0.15.198:15843 -> 74.125.140.127:19302
```

I receive it without the **barnyard2[62642]** part as such:

```
Aug  6 15:53:04 10.0.0.204 [1: 2025705:2] ET POLICY SMB2 NT Create AndX Request For a Powershell .ps1 File [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2]: <so-ens192-1> {TCP} 10.0.0.3:31055 -> 10.0.0.210:445
```

Any idea what can be wrong with the configuration?